# Make someone eat a blue sky

Tags: idioms, expressions, vocabulary

A friend of mine read in a book:

"Make that Gaou eat a blue sky...!"

Gaou is a character in the book. We do not have any idea what is the meaning of someone eating a blue sky, can you explain?

If the context is missing, I will ask her to edit my question :)

EDIT: thanks to comments, I am giving more details:

This is from a manga, its name is Eyeshield 21, chapter 272: winning, page 8

Comment: Is it a translation from another language? It doesn't mean anything in English as far as I know.

Comment: I have no idea what “eat a blue sky” means. If, as Old Brixtonian speculates, this is a translation, it clearly is not very good. If “Gaou” is a proper name, we almost never precede it with an article or demonstrative adjective.

Comment: A huge piece of context is missing:  the name of the book and a link to the phrase(if possible_  When you say "book" do you mean "video game" specifically [The Last Remnant](https://lastremnant.fandom.com/wiki/Gaou).

Comment: I have voted to close.  I suspect the answer is "Bad translation", certainly it isn't an idiom, It might be a metaphor or a humorous  reversal of "eat dirt" or something.  But as the question stands it is unanswerable.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian and others, thank you for your comments. I have edited adding informations hoping you won't close the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the same page the manga provides an explanation of what a Blue Sky is, "for those who forgot."

[image]

Transcribed:

> Note: for those who forgot, a Blue Sky is when the lineman sends the opponent flying parallel to the ground, so that all they can see is the blue sky.

Thus "eat a blue sky" = "knock him over on his back".

Within the given context, "eat" a blue sky would be understood as "force him to experience." It has connotations of humiliating; e.g. as in the loosely related idiom, "I'll make him eat his words."

Answer (score 2):

There is an explanation in [the manga](https://gseotools.my.id/course/) translation:

> Note: for those who forgot, a Blue Sky is when the lineman sends the opponent flying parallel to the ground so that all they can see is the blue sky. Not sure if it'll work well in this case since there's a roof, but it's the thought that counts.

This is an translator's note, the explanation doesn't appear in the [Japanese version](https://www.mangakakalot.is/read/eyeshield-21-110/ja/chapter-272)

I have no idea if this is a real term used in American football, or if it is a translation of a phrase used in American football in Japan.

The expression "Make that Gaou eat a Blue Sky" seems to be translationese: I found the [original Japanese](https://www.mangakakalot.is/read/eyeshield-21-110/ja/chapter-272), which reads (forgive the romanji)  *"Ano Gaou ni aoten kurareshite yareyo"*  The translator has translated the Japanese literally, word by word into English.

This is merely a poor translation.

Comment: I think [this](https://second-effort.com/term/aoten/) is where the translator got the idea from:「ブロックをされた選手が尻もちをついて倒れてしまうことを意味する」*It refers to a player who got blocked (?) fall on their bottom*

Comment: I've never heard this phrase used in the context of American football, which isn't played widely in Japan. I suspect that "lineman" might also be a position in some other sport (or that the translator used "lineman" incorrectly).